# Remove words starting with "_" in file using sed in bash

Tags: macos, bash, sed

Given:

```
this is a_REMOVEME test_REMOVEME for the win
```

I want to get:

```
this is a test for the win
```

What I currently have doesn't seem to do the trick as it only removes the `_`:

```
sed -e 's/_\w*//g' myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
sed -ie 's/_[A-Za-z0-9]* / /g' here.txt
```

Comment: Note this won't work completely if the pattern to remove is not followed by a space: `echo "foo_bar baz_qux" | sed 's/_[A-Za-z0-9]* / /g'`. I would write this as: `sed 's/_[[:alnum:]]*\([[:blank:]]\|$\)/\1/g'`

Comment: it didnt work if there was more than one dash

Answer (score 3):

`\w` may not be understood by your version of `sed` by default.  Instead of `\w` try, say, `[A-Za-z0-9]` or `[^ ]` to match any non-space characters.  You may also want to try `sed -re` to turn on extended regexp support.

Comment: or use `[[:alnum:]]*`

Comment: `-r` works on Linux, but not OSX - even its almost-equivalent on OSX, `-E`, won't work here, because OSX sed (at least as of OS X 10.9.1) never supports shortcut character classes such as `\w` (that would require so-called _enhanced_ regex features - a dimension separate from _extended_ regexes - which, sadly, most OSX tools do NOT support); `[[:alnum:]_]` in lieu of `\w` is your friend here. @glennjackman: while `[[:alnum:]]` is perfectly adequate here, let me point out that the exact equivalent of `\w` is `[[:alnum:]_]`.

Comment: @mklement0 Oh, I was suggesting `-r` not to solve the original problem but rather because I couldn't remember if `[` need to be escaped.  I didn't want the OP to try my solution and get even more confused ... I guess I messed that up!

Comment: @dg99 Got it; to be more specific: if you try to use `-r` with sed _on OSX_, you'll get a syntax error. `[` and `]` do NOT need escaping when enclosing a character set, even without `-r` / `-E`. Turning on `-r` (Linux) / `-E` (OSX) is generally a good idea, though (less escaping, more features) - the unfortunate thing is that there's no single flag that works on both platforms.

Comment: @mklement0, you do not want to include "_" in the character class because that's the field separator.

Comment: @glennjackman Fair point (though it'll work either way in the case at hand). Wanted to keep others from potentially mistakenly inferring that `\w` is the same as `[[:alnum:]]`, when in actuality it is `[[:alnum:]_]`.

Answer (score 0):

It's funny, if you have done that using command-line perl... it would work:

```
$ echo "this is a_REMOVEME test_REMOVEME for the win" | perl -pe 's/_\w*//g'

this is a test for the win
```